# It is appropriate select and translate best questions and answers from SO in English to post it on SO in Spanish when beta begin

Tags: discussion

Let me know if this behavior is appropriate on StackExchange.

Comment: What is the exact name of the beta site you are referring to? Is it about Spanish language or programming?

Comment: i refer to SO in Spanish

Comment: It's probably okay. Using question body as continuation of the title, on the other hand...